# Python 3: if/else statement skips straight to else

Tags: python, if-statement

Alright, so I was working on a Pig Latin translator (like the one in the Codecademy lessons, but more advanced), and it works, except for when I prompt the user if they want to translate another word or not, but the if/else statement that I give the user always skips to the else no matter what the input. The module gives no syntax errors or anything, and I don't see ANYTHING wrong with the code. This is the block from my program that is giving me issues:

```
def translator():
    job = input("Are you translating TO or FROM PygLatin? ")
    if job.upper() == "TO":
        word = input("Alright, what's the word we're translating? ")
        wordlength = len(word)
        firstletter = word[0]
        choppedword = word[1:wordlength]
        completeword = choppedword + firstletter + pyg
        print("Okay! Your translated word is...")
        time.sleep(3)
        print(completeword)
        time.sleep(3)
        redo = input("Wanna translate something else? Y/N ")
        if redo.upper == "Y":
            print("Awesome!")
            time.sleep(3)
            translator()
        else:
            print("Oh, okay then... Bye " + name + "!")
            sys.exit()
    elif job.upper() == "FROM":
        word = input("Alright, what’s the word we’re translating? ")
        wordlengthtwo = int(len(word))
        firstletterindex = int(wordlengthtwo - 3)
        firstletter = word[firstletterindex]
        choppedword = word[0:firstletterindex]
        newword = str(firstletter.upper() + choppedword)
        print("Okay! Your translated word is...")
        time.sleep(3)
        print(newword)
        time.sleep(3)
        again = input("Wanna translate something else? Y/N ")
        if again.upper == "Y":
            print("Awesome!")
            time.sleep(3)
            translator()
        else:
            print("Oh, okay then... Bye " + name + "!")
            sys.exit()
```

More specifically, these parts in the coding:

```
redo = input("Wanna translate something else? Y/N ")
if redo.upper == "Y":
    print("Awesome!")
    time.sleep(3)
    translator()
else:
    print("Oh, okay then... Bye " + name + "!")
    sys.exit()
```

And,

```
again = input("Wanna translate something else? Y/N ")
if again.upper == "Y":
    print("Awesome!")
    time.sleep(3)
    translator()
else:
    print("Oh, okay then... Bye " + name + "!")
    sys.exit()
```

So... Any ideas on why this may be happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Try "upper()", not "upper".

Comment: @gustafbstrom Thank you, that worked. I completely forgot about that part. Derp. :P

Comment: instead of editing the title of the question to say `solved`  the stackoverflow way of going about things is to accept an answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, I rewrote [your code in a much simpler way](https://gist.github.com/pzp1997/6136b59bdf1053930c07). Perhaps you might find it useful @YoloMcSwaggins.

Answer (score 3):

`str.upper` is a method. If you want the value of the string in upper case you should call this method.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing opening and closing parenthesis when calling the `str.upper` function

```
if redo.upper() == "Y":
    ...


if again.upper() == "Y":
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

when you have :

```
if again.upper == "Y":
```

It is comparing `again.upper` which is a function with the string `"y"`. This comparison will always be false and hence it will always evaluate the false branch.
Other languages don't permit usage of functions in this way and likely give you an error, this lack of an error might not be what you expect.

If you look at this with the REPL or similar you will see what's going on, this code snippet will hopefully help you understand what's going on:

```
test = "abcDEF"
print(test.upper)
print(test.upper())
```

this outputs:

```
<built-in method upper of str object at 0xb73ce300>
ABCDEF
```

You can see this in action here: http://ideone.com/gYyPnH